# React sync with local storage and update dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I am using a custom `useLocalStorage` hook defined:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

// Hook
function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
    // State to store our value
    // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
      try {
        // Get from local storage by key
        const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
        // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
        return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
      } catch (error) {
        // If error also return initialValue
        console.log(error);
        return initialValue;
      }
    });
  
    // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
    // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
    const setValue = value => {
      try {
        // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
        const valueToStore =
          value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
        // Save state
        setStoredValue(valueToStore);
        // Save to local storage
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
      } catch (error) {
        // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
  
    return [storedValue, setValue];
  }

  export default useLocalStorage;
```

in my main app, I have a searchbar and a list component, and I want to add whatever the user writes to the local storage and to list it below the searchbar, and this is what I tried doing :

```
function App() {
  const [data, changeData] = useLocalStorage('data', []);
  return {
   <div className="App">
   <SearchBar changeData={changeData} data={data}> </SearchBar>
        <ListComp data={data}> </ListComp>
   </div>
  }
```

Whereas ListComp looks like this :

```
class ListComp extends React.Component {

    

    render() { 
        const { data } = this.props;
        return data.map(
            city => <p key={city}> {city} </p>
        )
    }
}

export default ListComp
```

and SearchBar looks like this :

```
import { Input } from 'antd'

function SearchBar(props) {

  const { Search } = Input
  const { changeData, data } = props

  return (
      <>
    <div>
      <Search
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a city name"
        onSearch={(e) => {
            data.push(e)
            changeData(data)
        }}
      />

    </div>

    </>
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

The problem is that while the localStorage DOES update, my components don't seem to update and I can't see the updated list on the screen as soon as i press the button - I need to refresh to see it updated.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? I am very new to react and trying to learn it so i'd love some help!

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you tried console `data` inside App component after `changeData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mutate the previous state of the array. Try as the following:

```
setStoredValue(prevState => [...prevState, valueToStore]);
```

Comment: @GuySchwartzberg Awesome, happy to help!

Comment: Hi norbitrial, I am facing similar issue and tried to implement your solution but still no luck. do you mean to replace the line in the useLocalStorage hook? like changing this line `setStoredValue(valueToStore);` to this line `setStoredValue(prevState => [...prevState, valueToStore]);` because that didn't work. thanks :)
`